# 'gcloud' auth print-access-token Command is not recognizable from Process::fromShellCommandline('gcloud auth print-access-token')

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-platform, ocr, gcloud

I configured Google Cloud for OCR and authenticated user by ADC, and implemented complete logic in laravel 8 and php 7.4.19. To access the `access_token` I was running command `gcloud auth print-access-token` and it was returning token, but suddenly it started to give the error:

```
gcloud is not recognized as internal or external command
```

I am running command `usingSymfony\Component\Process\Process::fromShellCommandline('gcloud auth print-access-token')`. It was sending a token which I used to send REST API request at `https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate` to fetch image text. Everything was working fine on localhost but now, It is giving me the error

```
The command \"gcloud auth print-access-token\" failed.\n\nExit Code: 1(General error)\n\nWorking directory: \n\nOutput:\n================\n\n\nError Output:\n================\n'gcloud' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.
```

Even environment variables are set, still this is coming, which was not coming before

Comment: Where your code is running? On which service?

Comment: Hi @ayesha could you provide the details of the environment where you are running your code..?

Comment: OS is windows 11, and I run code on localhost using command 'php artisan serve'

Comment: @Ayesha this can be resolved by adding the environment variable, go to the path mentioned below 
```
MyComputer->Right Click - Properties -> Advanced System Settings - advanced - Environment Variables
```
and Under System variables in Environment variables choose 
```
PATH->Edit-> ADD "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin " and click OK.
```

Comment: @Ayesha is your issue resolved..? reply back if you are still facing the issue..